# capitalize words with some words inside of tags

Tags: php

Here's what I tried:

```
ucwords(strtolower('<span class="lsres">retro</span> VIRUS'));
```

I want to get:

```
Retro Virus
```

I am getting:

```
retro Virus
```

I cannot do anything similar to:

```
sprintf(ucwords(strtolower('%s VIRUS')), ucwords(strtolower('retro')));
```

Since "retro" part happens at the beginning, in the middle, or at the end of the word/sentence totally randomly.

Of course "retro" is a sample only and in different cases it can be replaced by other words at random.

Comment: What you need is a `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be necessary (see my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look into PHP's documentation [brought this up](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-convert-case.php).

And after a short test, I can confirm, that this line does the trick for your example (I don't know about any other specific cases you might have, though):

```
$str = '<span class="lsres">retro</span> VIRUS';
echo mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: unfortunately if you try convert, e.g: La <span class="lsres">Lond</span>e-Les-Maures, you will get: La LondE-Les-Maures, instead of: La Londe-Les-Maures (capital E pass "spanned" Lond)

Comment: well yeah. then you probably need a DOM parser. Because instead of span it could be div, which is a block element. And then Lond and e would not belong to the same word. You need to know a lot about the HTML structure (including semantics) to figure out all those cases. Do you actually have a case, where a word is split by an HTML-tag?

Answer (score 0):

you are getting `retro Virus` because there is no white space before and after retro(`>retro<`). Either add a space before retro or use `ucfirst` function or the same function that you have used individually on retro and VIRUS. Do it like this:

```
<span class="lsres"><?php echo ucfirst('retro');?></span> <?php echo ucfirst('VIRUS');?>
```

OR

```
<span class="lsres"><?php echo ucwords(strtolower('retro'));?></span> <?php echo ucwords(strtolower('VIRUS'));?>
```